# Dynamic DNS for professional servers

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dns-hosting, dyndns

This might sound like a unusual subject but recently I had major issues with changing DNS servers for our web apps and certain nameservers not releasing our domain names quick enough.

So I've been thinking about either signing up for DDNS servers and putting all our IP's/Domains on there so we can change quickly if needed - good idea?

Secondly is they any need or benefit to creating my own dynamic name server and if so what are the major benefit?

Sorry if this sounds like a open question but I am interested in the concept of DDNS for all of our domains

Comment: Why would one want to change DNS servers quickly?

Comment: Just to clarify this question, are you changing your glue and `NS` records frequently (i.e. changing who provides your DNS services or where your nameservers are located) or changing `A` and `CNAME` records frequently (i.e. changing where your web servers are)?

Comment: Changing where own servers are and which provider the domain name is linked to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDNS is just the same as regular DNS, it just uses a very low time to live. When migrating a server you have to put your own TTL very low (a few days before). One can not guarantee a fast propagation to *every* single DNS server on the WAN. There will always be a delay.